# join empty DataTables, show anyhow the Headers of the columns

Tags: c#, linq, join

I have a question about Linq join. I always had many DataTables and join them, worked great. But now if those Tables are empty, so Header of this columns is not able to see either. How can i do that, if those Tables are empty,  they show anyhow those headers.

Table 1:

```
Name  LastName ...
```

Table 2:

```
Name Comment ...
```

Result:

```
Name LastName Comment ...
```

My Code would be:

```
var res = from tb1 in Table1.AsEnumerable()
          join tb2 in Table2.AsEnumerable()
          on tb1.Field<String>("Name) equals tb2.Filed<String>("Name")
          Select new {
          Name = tb1.Field<String>("Name"),
          LastName= tb1.Field<String>("LastName"),
          Comment= tb2.Field<String>("Comment"),
```

But it doesn't show the headers of res. What did i do here wrong?
              }

Comment: Pls could you provide your tried code

Comment: Do you want the names of the fields or the values in one table, when the other table is null?

Comment: i want to display anyhow the header if the datatables are empty

Comment: It's because the result is anonymous type, not DataTable

Comment: OK, so is there anyway to join 2 empty DataTables?

Comment: Even your datatable are not empty, it still does not show header for you, you need to create new table

Comment: so how could i join 2 tables without linq?

Answer (score 0):

Could you do something like this?

```
var foo = from t in Table1.AsEnumerable
          select new
          {
              Name = ...,
              LastName = ...,
              Comment = null
          };
```

var bar = from t in Table2.AsEnumerable
          select new
          {
              Name = ...,
              LastName = null,
              Comment = ...
          };

var res = from x in foo
          join y in bar on y.Name == x.Name
          select new { /*Name, LastName, Comment */}

Note, the order of the properties must be the same.